# Spring 4 MVC @RequestMapping on URL with parameters

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, web

I am trying to implement an inline search form (if that makes sense). Basically, I want two mappings for this page.

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/application", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView view() {
        return new ModelAndView("application");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/application?search=t")
    public ModelAndView handleSearch() {
        CaseManager caseManager = new CaseManager();
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("application");
        modelAndView.addObject("caseList", caseManager.getCaseList());

        return modelAndView;
    }
```

So, `/application` is the main page of the web app. It has a search bar where a user can enter a handful of search parameters. When they click on search, the table of results should get populated on the page. I went with this route with no luck. I end up getting a 404 on `/application?search=t`.

The button's `href="WebappName/application?search=t"`

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated! I am new to this whole web dev world and got kind of thrown into the fire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use the `params` argument to the `@RequestMapping`:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html?is-external=true

e.g.:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/application" params="search")
```

If you want to capture the param value and do something with it or

```
@RequestMapping(value="/application" params="search=t")
```

if you want to dispatch to a specific param/value combination (looks like the fit in this case).